# Is it possible to group where clauses in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to group item based on ORDER NO Where sales made by login User

```
 $sales = KotOrder::orderBy('id','DESC')
 ->where('prepared_by', Auth::user()->id)
 ->get();
return view('settups.restaurant.pos.report', \compact('sales'));
```

[image]

And I tried this

```
    $sales = KotOrder::orderBy('id','DESC')
     ->groupBy('qrtxt')
     ->where('prepared_by', Auth::user()->id)
     ->get();
    return view('settups.restaurant.pos.report', \compact('sales'));
```

It gives out error

[image]

Comment: $sales = KotOrder::where('prepared_by', Auth::user()->id)
     ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
     ->distinct('qrtxt')
     ->get();
    return view('settups.restaurant.pos.report', \compact('sales'));

Try replace groupBy with distinct?

Comment: I have replaced groupBy with distinct it still display all items

Comment: Can replace the orderby id desc to latest() instead?  See if the result changes.

Comment: It looks like there are multiple items that has same order no (row 1, 3, 7). I'm guessing each of this will have a different id. When you group by using order no, it becomes one group and `id` is no longer a valid identifier of this group. Same is true for other columns unless you apply an aggregate function (for eg: sum(price))

Comment: Yes there are items that have the same order no I need to group them and sum their price

Comment: So instead of `select *` you specify the columns you want. Specify a `select` list in your query. Eg: `groupB(.)->where(..)->select(DB::raw('SUM(price) as total_price'))->get()`

Comment: now its working

Comment: This is what i have put all together............         $sales = KotOrder::groupBy('qrtxt')
                ->where('prepared_by', Auth::user()->id)
                ->select(DB::raw('qrtxt, SUM(price) as total_price'))
                ->get();